# How to find the global function?

Tags: c++, vim, ctags

I have a function name called setValue, used in many classes. Also, i have a global function by the same name. When i press C-], it goes to arbitrary setValue function. How do i directly jump to the global setValue function? It is really pain to use tnext every time to find if the function global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `C-]` returns multiple matches you can look up the list with

```
:ts
```

Then enter the number to jump to correct definition or dismiss the list.

---

When ctags does not help ...
You can search for occurances of `setValue` and then jump to the one that looks like definition.

```
:vim /setValue/ *                 <-- greps for setValue in all files
```

You can search only specific files, if you know that it is in header in subdirectory src or headers:

```
:vim /setValue/ src/*.h headers/*.h
```

once it's done do

```
:cope
```

to open a list, you can navigate up/down to select the definition that looks correct then jump to it with `<enter>`

You can close the list with

```
:clo
```

And later reopen it with

```
:cope
```

It will be there unless you have executed other commands that overwrite the list